# UIStepper with Decimals

Tags: swift

My Swift app uses the *UIStepper* object for doing a simple plus and minus for a value, but in the configuration it only accepts a round number as a Step. I want to configure my *UIStepper* that it makes steps with 0.5. 
I tried the following on the Value Changed event:

```
  @IBAction func changedValueOfStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        self.stepper.value = self.stepper.value * 0.5
        testLabel.text = String(self.stepper.value)
  }
```

But that doesn't work correctly. Should I do this on a different Event or change the code?

Comment: Try leaving stepper value as it is (not multiplying it by 0.5) but update your label with `self.stepper.value * 0.5`. So just remove first line inside your button event function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write this line in viewDidLoad method.

```
stepper.stepValue = 0.5
```

And then replace your code with this code.

```
@IBAction func changedValueOfStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
      testLabel.text = String(self.stepper.value)
}
```

Comment: But then the Value of the Stepper isn't changed.. I wanna fetch the value later with ``self.valueStepper.value```

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your requirement

Comment: Your `testLabel.text` assignment is wrong. There's no point of multiplying the value of stepper (`self.stepper.value`) by `0.5` if the step is set to `0.5` already.

Comment: @MihaiFratu I have updated my answer. Thanks for draw my attension. Actually I forgot to update that part.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify steps of 0.5 either in Code:

```
    stepper.value = 0.0
    stepper.stepValue = 0.5 //<-- This
    stepper.minimumValue = 0.0
    stepper.maximumValue = 10.0
```

Or in Storyboard:

[image]

In your function you can just update your label:

```
    @IBAction func changedValueOfStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        testLabel.text = String(self.stepper.value)
    }
```